# LocalStorage function delays on apply changes on add/remove class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a two radio buttons that display grid view or list view, depend on which one is selected. But I want to keep the view when the page reloads.
The default view es list view.
I make it work using localstorage, but i think i am doing something wrong because:

1- I repeat the code twice (It is the only way i could make it works)

2- If i select grid view, then reload, the view is show as list for 1 second and then change a grid automatically.

This is my js:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('typeView') == 'list') {
    $(".card-container").addClass("card-list");
    $('.card-container').removeClass('card-grid');
    $('.actions-list').show();
    $('.actions-grid').hide();
}

if (localStorage.getItem('typeView') == 'grid') {
    $('.card-container').addClass('card-grid');
    $('.card-container').removeClass('card-list');
    $('.actions-list').hide();
    $('.actions-grid').show();
}
$('#view-card-mode .list-view').off('click');
$('#view-card-mode .list-view').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('typeView', 'list');
    $('.card-container').removeClass('card-grid');
    $('.card-container').addClass('card-list');
    $('.actions-list').show();
    $('.actions-grid').hide();
});
$('#view-card-mode .grid-view').off('click');
$('#view-card-mode .grid-view').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('typeView', 'grid');
    $('.card-container').removeClass('card-list');
    $('.card-container').addClass('card-grid');
    $('.actions-list').hide();
    $('.actions-grid').show();
});
```

The html:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="view-card-mode">
  <label class="btn btn-default grid-view active" title="Vista de Grilla">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="grid-view" autocomplete="off" checked>
        <i class="fa fa-th"> </i>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default list-view" title="Vista de Lista">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="list-view" autocomplete="off">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different take, using a list of possible views and string interpolation.

```js
$(function() {

  // Sets up a list of possible views
  const views = ['list', 'grid'];

  function setView(view) {
    // sets the default to "grid"
    // use this if you only need to support modern browsers:
    // view = view ?? 'grid';
    // otherwise:
    view = view || 'grid';
    // Assuming there are only two views, gets the "other" view
    const other = views.find(v => v !== view);
    // adds the current view to the card container
    $(".card-container").addClass(`card-${view}`);
    // removes the old view from the card container
    $('.card-container').removeClass(`card-${other}`);
    // shows the actions for the current view?
    $(`.actions-${view}`).show();
    // hides the actions for the old view?
    $(`.actions-${other}`).hide();
    // set the appropriate radio button checked
    $(`#${view}-view`).prop('checked', true);
    // sets the local storage item to the new view
    localStorage.setItem('typeView', view);
  }

  // calls setView on page load for the value in local storage
  setView(localStorage.getItem('typeView'));

  // set the views in response to clicks
  $('#view-card-mode .list-view').on('click', function() {
    setView('list');
  });
  $('#view-card-mode .grid-view').on('click', function() {
    setView('grid');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

With the use of toggle and toggle class you can set a boolean. You can make the change code also simplier by using a value.

```js
$("#view-card-mode").on("change", 'input[type="radio"]', function () {
  // set localstorage to selected radio button
  localStorage.set('typeView', this.value);
  // alter the view
  toggleView();
})

function toggleView (selectRB) {
  // get the active selection
  var value = localStorage.get('typeView') || 'grid-view';
  var isList =  value === 'list-view';
  // toggle based on the selections
  $('.card-container').toggleClass('card-grid', !isList);
  $('.card-container').toggleClass('card-list', isList);
  $('.actions-list').toggle(!isList);
  $('.actions-grid').toggle(isList);
  // if load, set the selected radio button to synced with local storage
  if (selectRB) {
    $("input[name=radio][value=" + value + "]").prop('checked', true);
  }
}

toggleView(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="view-card-mode">
  <label class="btn btn-default grid-view active" title="Vista de Grilla">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="grid-view" autocomplete="off" checked  value="grid-view">
        <i class="fa fa-th"> </i>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default list-view" title="Vista de Lista">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="list-view" autocomplete="off" value="list-view">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```